# Why does my onclick"" not work?

Tags: javascript, html, audio, dictionary, onclick

Disclaimer: Don't worry about my code being "standards compliant"

Basically, the page I am making is supposed to play a short audio clip upon loading using the `<object data="someAudio.wav">` tag. I then use Javascript and setTimeout() to play a couple of other audio files after a few seconds of delay. The setTimeout does this by using innerHTML and rewriting the correct div section with with a new object, where the object is just another audio. For example:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
setTimeout("update_audio()", 2500);

function update_audio(){
    document.getElementById('slide_audio').innerHTML="<object classid='clsid:22D6F312-B0F6-11D0-94AB-0080C74C7E95' height='0' width='0'><param name='FileName' value='../../../Audio_general/good.wav'><param name='autoplay' value='true'><object type='audio/mpeg' height='0' width='0' data='../../../Audio_general/good.wav'><param name='controller' value='true'><param name='autoplay' value='false'></object></object>";
}
</script>
```

I have the image linked to a map so that it is divided up into the 4 sections. When I click on a section, it will call a function that will perform logic based on my selection and then should play 1 of 2 other audio files. Section of map code here:

```
<map id="testing_image" name="pictureMap">
    <area id="image1" shape="rect" coords="0, 0, 449, 331"  onclick="evaluate_status(1);" onmouseover="this.style.cursor='pointer'" alt="FB">
</map>
```

My problem is, the `onclick="evaluate_status()"` parts of the map will only work before I update the innerHTML. Meaning, if I can click on a section before 2.5 seconds (the first innerHTML update) it will play the correct audio. However, after it updates the div section using innerHTML, none of the onclicks of my map will work. I am confused as to why this is since only a small  section is being changed.

Can anyone help me figure out why the onclicks don't work and how I can fix it? I am still pretty new to web design and really need the assistance. Thanks!

Comment: The audio will for sure work on IE if it doesn't play on your other browser. Don't worry about this now.

Comment: is `testing_image` a child of `slide_audio` by chance? otherwise can you show us the code of `evaluate_status` and or a little more of your html

Comment: added `function`. and no, `id="slide_audio"` is the `<div>` section that only contains the initial `<object data="audio.wav"></object>` so that I can replace it with the JS later on

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're missing a closing `</div>` tag for `slide_audio`, therefore `testing_image` in fact is a child of `slide_audio` and is being replaced with the new object when the script runs.

If you look in Firebug with JavaScript disabled you'll be able to see that `testing_image` is inside `slide_audio`, not separate from it.  Here's a screenshot of Chrome's Developer Tools on that site:

[image]

Comment: Correct, here's a screenshot with Chrome's developer tools: https://www.dropbox.com/s/51chgypd7ol48c0/divs.jpg.  Most likely this was due to missing closing `</div>` tags; this is an example of how much trouble you can run into later on.

Comment: Omg... I wrote `<div>` instead of `</div>` for the closing tag... I can't believe how one stupid thing like that can cause so much trouble lol. I'll have to check out those debugging tools. THANK YOU SO MUCH

Answer (score 0):

Can you show of evaluate_status() function?
Also for the first code

setTimeout("update_audio()", 2500);

function update_audio(){
    document.getElementById('slide_audio').innerHTML="";
}

You should define the function before you use it in settimeout. This will not generate error in Chrome, but in other browsers, it will.